# wifi passwords in keyring

Tags: wireless, keyrings

at my work we use a leap network (you login onto the wifi using a username and password)

It is a Tunneled TLS network with a MSCHAPv2 inner authentication. Because of this the password in stored inside the keyring and is encrypted until I log on.

The problem now rises that every time I boot my laptop at work the wifi login screen pops up when I'm entering my password to login onto my laptop.

When this screen pops up I cannot enter my password to login onto my laptop and I have to click it away and finish my password. This is getting really annoying since it pops up again after about 5 seconds. I was wondering if there is a way to stop (or at least suspend) the attempted login onto the leap networks until the keyring is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the settings of this particular WiFi network inside your Ubuntu laptop.

**Steps:**

1. Click on the WiFi icon on right side of the top panel.
2. Select "Edit Connections..."
3. Under **WiFi** find and select the SSID of the WiFi hotspot you are
   having trouble with.
4. Click on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button on the right to edit the
   settings of the WiFi SSID. [image]
5. Go to the **General Tab.**
6. Unselect "All users may use this network". This will make this WiFi
   network connect after you login and won't let anyone else use this
   particular WiFi when they login with their own userID.
7. Optionally: Uncheck "Automatically connect to this network when it
   is available." This will allow you to manually select this WiFi
   network when you are ready to connect.[image]
8. Click on <kbd>Save...</kbd> button on the bottom of this window to save
   the settings. Provide password if prompted.
9. Close the **Network Connections** window by clicking on
   <kbd>Close</kbd> button and you are done.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think this would do the trick.
I'll try it tomorrow